# How to put focus on or select an install wizard screen from Jenkins build

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I have a PowerShell script that uses SendKeys to control the button presses of an install wizard (msi).

I want to automate the running of this PS and was going to use Jenkins as I have other auto processes to do.

The problem I have is when I run the PS from Jenkins, the installer screen pops up, but flashes as it is waiting for something to select it.

Can I make the focus go to the installer screen?

My PS code is

```
    #Launch installation wizard
Msiexec -i C:\Auto-Installer\Installer.Wix.msi /L*V "C:\Auto-Installer\Install-log.txt"

#Wait 15 seconds for disk scan to complete
sleep 15

#Set-up variable
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;

#Select the install wizard screen
$wshell.AppActivate('Install Setup')

#Enter on the Next button - Welcome screen
$wshell.SendKeys("{ENTER}")
sleep 3

#Enter on the Next button - Use current licence file screen
$wshell.SendKeys("{ENTER}")
sleep 3

#Enter on the Next button - Confirmation of licence file screen
$wshell.SendKeys("{TAB}")
$wshell.SendKeys("{ENTER}")
sleep 3

#Enter on the Next button - Please back up DB screen
$wshell.SendKeys("{TAB}")
$wshell.SendKeys("{ENTER}")
```

Thanks.

Ian.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Just needed to uncheck the "Use PowerShell Profile" option, now it selects the window]

Just needed to uncheck the "Use PowerShell Profile" option, now it selects the window